# "There are no fingerprint readers available at this time" error. On my windows 8 HP 64bit

Tags: windows, windows-8, fingerprint

After a refresh of my system. I couldn't log in windows with my finger print anymore. I tried updating the driver, but it says up to date.
Please help my system make is HP envy m6 Notebook PC, 64 bit, version 6.2.9200 Build 9200.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Reinstall the device after you remove it then setup your authentication again

Comment: I've done that. Still doesn't work

Comment: When you removed the device you also checked the delete the drivers option?  Have you setup the authentication again?

Comment: Nope.
But here is the latest
After some months i just checked now and i got this message about the driver

"Windows cannot start this hardware device because its configuration information (in the registry) is incomplete or damaged. (Code 19)"

Comment: Months? Alright; use DISM and sfc to repair the damage

Comment: Now i need real help.
What's DISM & SFC?

Comment: If you searched for both those terms you wouldn't be asking that question

Comment: lols
I asked same time i searched
Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score -1):

When you say "Updating the driver" I assume you mean "Run Windows Update".  Instead, go to the manufacturer's website and look for Support or Drivers or Downloads.  There, find your computer's model and download the appropriate drivers for it.  It will probably have multiple versions and confusing naming standards - it might be called Biometric Security or Fingerprint Reader or something else.

Windows Update only has a computer's unique drivers if both the manufacturer and Microsoft team up and both do significant amounts of work to put the unique drivers on the list.  It's a lot easier for the manufacturer to just put the drivers on their website.

Comment: your assumption is Wrong.
You can update drivers individually.
Trust me, i also got another driver from my manufacturer but didn't work